# geom_path() adds extra paths connecting state polygons while plotting precipitation climatology over a country?

Tags: r, ggplot2, polygon, ggmap

I have a question regarding how to effectively add state level polygon borders while plotting mean precipitation over India. I downloaded the level 1 shape file from [here](http://gadm.org/country). Let me briefly explain the code chunks here:

First I read the data after downloading and created the data frame:

```
ds <- readOGR(dsn = datdir, layer = "IND_adm1")
sub.ds <-ds[ds$NAME_1 != "Andaman and Nicobar" & ds$NAME_1 !="Lakshadweep",]
# Fortify
indFrame<- fortify(sub.ds,region="NAME_1")
```

The mean precipitation data (*precipM*) can be downloaded from (url=[here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/subhomoyghosh/monsoon-precipitation/master/meanPrecipitation.csv))

```
download.file("url",method=curl)
precipM<- read.csv()
```

Basically the data frame looks like long, lat, precipitation:

```
       lat long precipitation
1 23.5 68.5      1.104472
2 24.5 68.5      1.075727
3 21.5 69.5      1.724481
4 22.5 69.5      1.137294
5 23.5 69.5      1.042384
6 24.5 69.5      1.019344
```

Then I used ordinary kriging over the gridded mean precipitation to generate a sample data over entire India. I used my own function *krig()* but potentially any method works.

```
    grd <- spsample(sub.ds, type = "regular", n = 50000)
    ans<- krig(grd@coords,precipM)
```

Then I tried to plot the map (with the states) + data in the following way:

```
p1<- ggplot(aes(x = long, y = lat, fill = precipitation), data = ans) + 
  geom_raster() + scale_fill_continuous(low = "white", high = muted("blue"))  +
  coord_equal()+ geom_path(data = indFrame,aes(fill=NULL),colour = "black", size = .75)
p1
```

But I am getting a very weird shaped plot with state level polygons connected. You can follow the same link (where I uploaded the data in *monsoon-precpitation* folder) to look at the picture.

Any help is highly appreciated?

Comment: I have just found a solution to this problem. We have to declare group variable inside aes() in geom_path(). But could anyone tell me the reason?

Comment: The 'group' aesthetic tells ggplot which subset of the data (state polygon, in this case) a given point belongs to; without that aesthetic, ggplot cannot distinguish states and simply connects all points in order.